# Resfreshing a page would lose parameters posted

Tags: c#, reload, page-refresh

I want to refresh/reload a page within a frameset. The content of that page is based on the selection done in a dropdownlist. Alternatively the selected value can also be passed through a query parameter.

Whatever I tried of the below solutions would just reload the page without reposting the selected value. (I dont't wont the see the DropDownList saying: Choose the User)

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); - called from a LinkButton  

<a href="horas_admin.aspx?ID=<% { Response.Write(DdUser.SelectedValue); }%>#hoy" target="Details" style="border:none"><img src="/img/reload.png" border="0"></a>
```

The second solution points to the correct url, but just works if opened in a new window; otherwise the content wont be refreshed.

---

I found a solution that works perfectly for me by adding another query parameter with a random value that changes all the time. That forces a reload, bypassing the cache.

The random value is built from the timeportion of DateTime.now, eliminating the ":" and trailing blanks.

```
<a href="horas_admin.aspx?ID=<% { Response.Write(DdUser.SelectedValue+"&a="+Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now).Substring(11).Replace(":","").Trim()); }%>#hoy" target="Details" style="border:none"><img src="/img/reload.png" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Solved! I added the solution that works for me.